# delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this problem which I have been stuck on but have an answer but not sure exactly why it's working... Please can someone explain why this works?

```
function deleteNth(arr,n){

   var cache = {};
    return arr.filter(num => {
      cache[num] = (cache[num]||0) + 1; // this is the line i am comfused about!!
      return cache[num] <= n;
    });
  
  }

deleteNth([1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2], 3);
```

Comment: The function is using the built-in filter function to limit the size of the array. See MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `(cache[num]||0) + 1` - this line checks the `cache` object for the key `[num]`. If it exists, 1 is added to that count. If `count[num]` is a falsy value, `0 + 1` will be added together. `cache[num]` will be undefined for every new number that is added in the `cache` for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So through the filter function it'll run for each of the elements in the array.

The line you are confused about is setting the cache[num].

In the first iteration, num will be 1, and cache will be equal to {}, so cache[num] will be undefined.

It is setting it to (cache[num] || 0) which in real terms means if cache[num] OR 0. As cache[num] is undefined in the first instance, it'll be 0. It is then adding 1.

so each time the number is hit, it is adding one, and then it will return if the number of instances is below or equal the accepted number, in this case 3.

When it goes above that threshold, it'll be equal to false and now it won't be included as part of the filter.

Comment: That explains it perfectly, Thanks, Nick!

Answer (score 1):

`cache[num]||0` means that if `cache[num]` doesn't have a key `num` then use the value 0.
This happens because the value `cache[num]` can be null in the first occurence

```js
var cache = {}
console.log(cache[1]);      // undefined
console.log(cache[1] || 0); // 0
```

Comment: _"`cache[num]||0` means that if `cache[num]` doesn't have a key `num` then use the value 0"_ - more accurate statement would be that if `cache[num]` is a falsy value, then `cache[num]||0` will evaluate to zero.

Comment: Great Help, Thank you!